# paypal success url return null

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

i have simple paypal checkout form when i post it to paypal with sandbox credential when the paypments success, it gives me nothing like transaction and currency, i did print GET, but there is nothing. i am using codeigniter

below is the form code

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_click">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="dev1@ferozitech.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test" class="slug">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="2" class="proposalId">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="" class="userId">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="40" class="amount">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base_url('payment/payment_complete/') ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo base_url('payment/payment_cancel') ?>">
<input type="image" name="submit" src="<?php echo base_url('images/checkoutpaypal.png'); ?>" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
</form>
```

Comment: where is notify input field?

Comment: i just copied above code from developer, did i missed something.??

Comment: yes, u missed this `<input type="hidden" value="<?=$notify_url;?>" name="notify_url" id="paypal_notify_url">` notify_url

Comment: what will be the $notify_url? what is it for???

Comment: `http://www.codexworld.com/how-to-guides/paypal-ipn-notify-url-not-working-sandbox-account/` this will help u, when u want to check paypal response, than you must need to use notify url, it will give you payment status notification in `$_POST`

Comment: thank you. i will look at that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this code:


<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="dev1@ferozitech.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test" class="slug">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="2" class="proposalId">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="" class="userId">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="40" class="amount">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base_url('payment/payment_complete/') ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo base_url('payment/payment_cancel') ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo base_url('payment/payment_complete/') ?>" />
<input type="image" name="submit" src="<?php echo base_url('images/checkoutpaypal.png'); ?>" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online"> 
</form>

Return url notify_url payment_complete function

print_r($_REQUEST);die;
```